# Quarkus and OpenAPI / SwaggerUI : Why are null values in JSON examples suppressed?

Tags: openapi, swagger-ui, quarkus

I have written a Quarkus REST endpoint which may have `null` values. I'm using Quarkus 3.5.3 with `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive`, `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson` and `io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi`.

My example response is defined like this:

```
  static final String RESPONSE_ALL =
    """
      {
        "foo": "bar",
        "baz": null
      }
    """;
```

However, this is what I see in SwaggerUI:

[image]

Apparently, any value that is `null` is suppressed by SwaggerUI. I see the same when the example is a REST parameter.

Should I configure something differently? Or is this a bug?

Comment: How have you defined the schema? Is `baz` listed as a `nullable: true` property?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I annotated the required fields with `jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull`, but forgot to configure the Schema fully. So I added `@Schema(description = "bla bla", nullable = true, required = false)` to `baz`, but it doesn't make any difference: That field is still suppressed.

Comment: Does the OpenAPI response get returned including `baz` in the example? If so, we'll know if it's Swagger UI or the OpenAPI that's to blame.

Comment: If I understand you right, you're asking whether the actual response contains null values. Yes, it does.

Comment: I mean - does the raw OpenAPI response from `/q/openapi` (assuming the default endpoint in Quarkus) include `baz` in the example for the schema?

Comment: Ah, now I understand. No, they are not present in the OpenAPI YAML. So it looks like it's a problem during the build.

Comment: I've found the code that is skipping the serialization of the null value: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/blob/4389f3ab7af8b15b22789af598fa1c1baecf9378/core/src/main/java/io/smallrye/openapi/runtime/io/ObjectWriter.java#L76-L78

Please open an issue in https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api and we will get it fixed.

Comment: Great - thanks a lot! I've opened an issue: https://github.com/smallrye/smallrye-open-api/issues/1773

If you add your comment as answer, I can approve it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug/missing feature in versions of smallrye-open-api, a library that is used by Quarkus for MicroProfile OpenAPI support. The problem was fixed and the `example` snippet you gave will render correctly in the OpenAPI response, starting with version 3.11 of smallrye-open-api.